# Foreach issue in c#

Tags: c#, .net

I'm writing a simple console note app, and having some issues with "foreach" function. When I enter "View", the notes should be displayed in order, but for each note I get "0", instead '0' '1' '2'.

[image: notes pic]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace note_app_console

{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)

        {
            List <String> notes = new List<string>();
            Console.WriteLine("Notes");
            int userInput;
            

            //main loop
            do
            {
                string addNote;
                //selecting action from menu
                userInput = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

                switch (userInput)
                {
                    case 1:

                        Console.WriteLine("Enter the note content: ");
                        addNote = Console.ReadLine();
                        notes.Add(addNote);
                        Console.WriteLine("Note added.");
                        break;

                    case 2:

                        Console.WriteLine("Your notes: ");
                        foreach (string i in notes)
                        {
                            int indexNote = i.IndexOf(i);
                            Console.WriteLine($"{Convert.ToString(indexNote)}. {i}");
                            

                        }

                        break;

                        
                }
                
            } while (userInput != 4);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are searching the index of _i_ in _i_ It should be the _notes_.IndexOf(i)

Comment: Better yet use a `for` loop where you have the index or just create the index before the loop and increment it in the loop instead of searching the list for an index.

Comment: FYI what you are currently doing is searching for the index of a substring in a string where the substring is the string and that will always return 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three options here

1. Use the `notes.IndexOf()`

   ```
   foreach (string item in notes)
   {
       int indexNote = notes.IndexOf(item);
       Console.WriteLine($"{indexNote}. {item}");                                                   
   }
   ```
2. Use a counter

   ```
   int counter = 0;
   foreach (string item in notes)
   {
       Console.WriteLine($"{counter}. {item}");                                                   
       counter++;
   }
   ```
3. Use a for loop

   ```
   for(int i=0; i<notes.Count; i++)
   {
       Console.WriteLine($"{i}. {notes[i]}");                                                   
   }
   ```

Note that there is no need to convert the integer into a string in the `WriteLine()` statement as the string interpolation does that automatically.

Answer (score 0):

First, your variable names are confusing. change the `foreach (string i in notes)` to `foreach (string note in notes)`.

Second, look for the index of the current note in the notes array, so change the `i.IndexOf(i)` to `notes.IndexOf(note)`

```js
foreach (string note in notes)
{
    int idx = notes.IndexOf(note);
    Console.WriteLine($"{Convert.ToString(idx)}. {note}");
}
```